# How to create round cornered textbox in Basic4Android

Tags: android, basic4android

I am trying to customize the UI of application in Basi4Application. Its been just 3 days am using it. So I need help with customization of UI. So far I have made this changes and still learning. Can anyone point me to any tutorials or website which talks about customization of UI in Basic4Android.
[image] 
The Username Edittext is by default displayed like this want to make look like something like this.Please refere below image.
[image] Someone please help me . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Create xml file in drawable folder-

rounded_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
    <stroke
          android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#4D4D4D"
        ></stroke>

</shape>
```

& in your layout code-

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"  
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
             />
```

Comment: You can set any value what you want for height. like 40dp,50dp .. or WRAP_CONTENT

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/white_lite" />

<stroke android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/purple_dark"/>

</shape>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#60FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#1c6aaa" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

rounded_corner.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <shape
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">

  <!-- view background color -->
 <solid
    android:color="#a9c5ac" >
</solid>

<!-- view border color and width -->
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#1c1b20" >
</stroke>

<!-- If you want to add some padding -->
<padding
    android:left="4dp"
    android:top="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:bottom="4dp"    >
</padding>

<!-- Here is the corner radius -->
<corners
    android:radius="10dp"   >
</corners>
</shape>
```

And keep this drawable as background for the view to which you want to keep rounded corner border. Let’s keep it for a LinearLayout

```
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am not working with Eclipse. I am using Basic4Android Application to make the application. How this be done in that application.

Answer (score 0):

The default Edit text looks different in different phones and emulators. Eg: Try older emulators, you will get nice round rectangle. While labels are easy to round, Edit text is not. You can customize using 9 patch images. See B4A forum. Forum browsing is free. Only library download is restricted.

Answer (score 0):

I should point you to the B4A forums where all the knowledgebase of the B4A IDE is.
http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/

There is a lot of UI related discussion there too, just to point to some random tutorials there:

> http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/how-they-do-1.20878/
>   http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/how-they-do-2.20970/
>   http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/how-they-do-3.21137/

...and there is a lot more.

For the edit text you can use a ColorDrawable or a 9Patch image.